# Variable arrays in class context

Tags: php, class, oop, object

I am trying to accomplish a simple class method where the user submit its name to a form and it returns a greeting message for every name on the variable array, such as "Welcome John", "Welcome Mike", etc...

Doing this as a regular function is easy:

```
$arr = array('Mike', 'John', 'Molly', 'Louis');
 function Hello($arr) {
    if(is_array($arr)) {
        foreach($arr as $name) {
            echo "Hello $name" . "<br>";    
        }
    } else {
        echo "Hello $arr";  
    }
}

Hello($arr);
```

However, I can't make it work in class context:

```
$arr = array('Mike', 'John', 'Molly', 'Louis');
class greetUser {
    public $current_user;   

    function __construct($current_user) {
        $this->current_user = $current_user;    
    }

    public function returnInfo() {
        if(is_array($this->current_user)) {
            foreach($this->current_user as $name) {
                echo "Welcome, " . $name;
            }
        } else {
           echo "Welcome, " . $this->current_user;
        }
    }   
}


    $b = new greetUser(''.$arr.'');
    $b->returnInfo();
```

Comment: `new greetUser(''.$arr.'');` why are you *attempting* to concatenate two empty strings to the array. Just do `new greetUser($arr);`

Answer (score 0):

replace your $b = new greetUser(''.$arr.''); with $b = new greetUser($arr); and it will work :)

Answer (score 0):

I was commiting a very silly mistake, as users pointed out, I was concatenating the variable when it was not necessary!